# Clang Tidy Addon for Visual Studio Code not working / How to setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-tidy

So I installed the Addon for Clang-Tidy in Visual Studio Code which can be found here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=notskm.clang-tidy

However after installing nothing is going on.

In the Instructions there is a demo were you just click on a file and see the Errors found by tidy but In my Visual Studio Code nothing happens.

What are the steps to set it up?

Answer (score 3):

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE: There is a [clangd VS Code Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) That works well.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The Clang-Tidy plugin is **not** being maintained: https://github.com/notskm/vscode-clang-tidy/issues/45

The developer has officially put it on indefinite hiatus.

**Also note:** You need clang-tidy installed on your system. I did this on my Ubuntu OS using the package manager. `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y clang-tidy`.